How do I prevent virtual environments having access to system packages?
noob here. I have a dockerised jupyter lab instance where I have a bunch of packages installed for the root user, and now I want to add an additional kernel that has no packages at all (yet). Here's how I've tried to do that:
# SYSTEM SETUP
FROM python:3.11.5-bookworm

ADD requirements/pip /requirements/pip
RUN pip install -r /requirements/pip
RUN mkdir /venv/ \
    && cd /venv/ \
    && python -m venv blank \
    && /venv/blank/bin/pip install ipykernel \
    && /venv/blank/bin/python -m ipykernel install --user --name=blank-env

I expect the root python environment to have all the packages listed in my requirements/pip file and my blank-env environment to be empty.
However, when I run jupyter lab in the docker container and select the blank-env kernel, it appears to have access to all of the packages from my requirements file. What am I doing wrong here?

Can't comment on anything jupyter specific (never touched it and never will), but I'm assuming the issue is that you're installing the requirements with the global pip and thus install it system-wide. A new virtualenv will include everything from the base python installation, if you want the packages to only be available in some contexts you would have to create different virtualenvs and install the packages only in the ones where you need them.

according to this link there is a --system-site-packages which gives the virtual environment access to the system site-packages dir. This seems to imply that it shouldn't be the case by default?

Removed the jupyter label as I now realise this has nothing to do with jupyter.

Can not reproduce. I used your Dockerfile, unchanged, and created a requirements/pip file with jupyterlab and some other unrelated packages, built it with docker build . -t myimg, ran it with docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888 myimg1 jupyter lab --allow-root --ip 0.0.0.0 and connected without issues. The blank-env kernel was working as expected, and unrelated packages were not available. Please edit more context into the question to make a reproducible example.

@wim yup you're right. My real code was running ipykernel install in the root virtual env rather than blank, so it was called blank-env but was actually root. That makes this question rather uninteresting. Will delete. Thanks for checking this.


Check Kernel Configuration: Make sure that when you install the ipykernel in your blank-env, you are activating the virtual environment before installing it.
FROM python:3.11.5-bookworm

ADD requirements/pip /requirements/pip
RUN pip install -r /requirements/pip

RUN python -m venv /venv/blank
RUN /venv/blank/bin/pip install ipykernel
RUN /venv/blank/bin/python -m ipykernel install --user --name=blank-env


Restart Jupyter Lab Server

Verify Kernel Environment
import sys
sys.executable



This will show you the path to the Python executable that the kernel is using. If it's pointing to the global Python environment, then there might be an issue with how the kernel was installed or activated.
